# Access denied for external drives (FAT32) on Windows7 , Diskpart, takeown, nothing works

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, fat32

I have been trying (without any success) to access 2 external harddrives and a USB key on Windows 7, the 3 with FAT32 format. (for the fun I also formatted one in ExFat to try, didn't work)

The access is denied each time (the 3 devices work perfectly on Mac) ;
I tried :

- To change the permission on the disk
- To run takeown (on cmd and powershell)
- To run it as an hidden administrator
- To format it, clean it, change the attributes with DiskPart
- To format it through Disk Management (formatted it, still didn't get the access)
- To change the security key to 0 to get the permission

Each time, I get "Access denied".

Little challenge, I am currently recovering 2To of data from another harddrive with TestDisk, so I cannot restart the computer.

Any idea ?

Comment: Many external drives have a switch or jumper that declares them read-only. Check for that in the docu.

Comment: FAT32 doesn't have file permissions.....just saying so taking ownership of a file or folder can't be done

Comment: I wonder if it's the computer, or the data storage device(s).  Have you tried accessing this data on another computer?

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: floflos404, any feedback?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was HP device access manager. Removing the program solved the issue.

[Link where I found the solution.](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/Access-Denied-on-USB-drives/m-p/3669132#M189675)

Relevant text:

> just bought a new HP ProBook 450 G1... running Windows 7...I inserted
>   a USB flash drive to copy some some files from my other compute, and
>   got the Windows Messgae "You don't currently have access to open this
>   folder", then I press the "continue" button, and get the message "You
>   have been denied permission to access this folder", and it says "To
>   gain access to this folder you will need to use the security tab".   I
>   click on the "security tab" link, but there is not any "security tab"
>   in the properties menu for the flash drive.   My logon is the
>   administrator and has all accesses checked'.   I also tried other
>   flash drives and a USB harddrive, and access was denied on all of
>   them.   Not sure if this is a Windows 7 issue or an issue with the
>   pre-loaded HP software, which I will probably unistall, but waiting to
>   see if you have an easy fix for this ?

---

> It was the pre-installed "HP Device Manager" causing the denied
>   access.   For some reason, at first, the proper ballon messages were
>   not being disaplayed, but later after some restarts, I noticed the
>   message.   So I uninstalled it, and I now have access to the external
>   drives... sure don't need that hassle of entering my password
>   everytime I attach a flash driver or external hard drive (and it only
>   giving me access for 15 minutes).   Maybe there's was a way to change
>   the parameters within  the HP Device Manager... but ain't nobody got
>   time for that ! Smiley Happy

Answer (score 2):

New HP Probook 470 G5 windows 10 Pro I had the exact same issue, and just uninstalled "HP Device Access Manager" and all of my USB drives worked just fine! 8GB USB thumb drive, 500GB Toshiba old laptop disk, 1TB Seagate FreeAgent Desk.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you checked within `Device Manager` to see if there are any visible problems with your USB controller?  If not, when you finally have the opportunity to power-cycle your machine that may alleviate the problem.  USB ports can occasionally be a bit temperamental, and performing a full shutdown on the machine for a few minutes can often help alleviate the problem.

This also sounds like what we see when someone has enabled the Group Policy settings to disable removable media.  Double check the settings within the following areas:

> Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Removable Storage Access
>
> User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Removable Storage Access

On the other hand, if this machine is using Windows 7 Home and can't access the group policy editor, you can check to see if the equivalent registry keys exist:

> HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices
>
> HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices